# Is there a better way to override CSS on an MUI TextInput with Chips

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm playing with MUI and react. I want to chips to appear in the text field to the left/above any text input.

The primary example I saw, was this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-input-with-chips-0s2j4, but it does not handle infinite chips...

I have it mostly working. Chips are using input adornment of the textfield (per the linked sandbox), like so:

```
<TextField
  sx={{"& .MuiInputBase-adornedStart": { flexDirection: 'column'}, display: 'flex'}}
  id="standard-basic" label="Participants" variant="standard" InputProps={{
    startAdornment:
      <Paper
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'left',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          listStyle: 'none',
          padding: 0,
          margin: 0,
          width: 1,
        }}
        component="ul"
        elevation={0}
      >
        {selected.map(data => {
          return (
            <ListItem key={data.key} sx={{margin: '0', width: 'min-content'}}>
              <Chip
                label={data.name}
                onDelete={deleteSelected(data)}
              />
            </ListItem>
          );
        })}
      </Paper>
  }}
/>
```

This works great, and gives the desired effect so that when chips are in the textbox, the input text shows up below the paper containing the chips!  Chips on top, input below, all within the textbox.

If I omit the `& .MuiInputBase-adornedStart": { flexDirection: 'column'}` portion and instead use `sx={{flexDirection: 'column', display: 'flex'}}`, no matter what I do, that direction does not stick when the page renders, because the style is applied to a div that contains the label, the text and the paper, rather than the textfield contents...

My questions are thus: is there a way to do this without overriding the nested component style (described at https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#the-sx-prop)? Is this a bad practice? Will it cause problems in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit here, but by the class name, the style needs to be on the Input component.  You can access the Input properties by using the `InputProps` property of the MUI `Textfield` ([see the API notes](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/)) instead of the Mui class name on the parent component.  For example:

```js
  <TextField
    {...}
    InputProps = {{
      sx={{ 
        [...CSS styles for the Input component here]
      }
    }}
  />
```

The code above may not work in your case, but you can access the properties of the nested `Input` component with the `InputProps` property.  This way you may not need to use the Mui class names to access the element.